# Python/Flask How to display banner on session expiration

Tags: python, flask, session-timeout, flask-session

I am working on a web application in Flask, and I want to display a banner to the user whenever the session times out. For the banner I am using the Flask's `flash("Session expired", "danger")` method, but the problem I am having is displaying the banner after the session refreshes.

I am using code similar to the following to set the session expiration time:

```py
@app.before_request
def set_timeout():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=60)
    session.modified = True
```

This works for expiring the session after the set period of inactivity, but I can't seem to display my `flash()` banner appropriately. Is there an easy way to check if the session has expired and display the banner accordingly? Something like:

```py
@app.before_request
def show_banner():
    if previous_session_expired: # <- How do I calculate this?
        flash("Session expired", "danger")
```

Comment: You would need javascript running on the web page that would periodically check the session token and display an alert when it expires.